# How to resize table column in angular 5

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular5

I want to achieve a resizable column table in angular5 .

1) Using CSS property resize -> Problem with this is that it doesnot work in IE.

2) Using Jquery col resizable function -> Gives error that resizable is not a function.

Is there any other way to achieve this in angular5. We have a HTML Table and want to resize a specific column without disturbing the others columns.

Comment: The solution will likely depend on what browsers you need to support. If you need support for everything back as far as IE8 the answer will be way more complicated than if it's just the latest Chrome

Comment: i have try example in this link i am getting errors .is  there any simple way do colomn resize   https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/colresize

Answer (score 1):

The easier way is to use javascript plugin in your component. I used alvaro's jquery plugin https://github.com/alvaro-prieto/colResizable and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngpq-table-resize Just install it, and add the tableResize directive to your table.

The library automatically adds resizing lines that can be edited.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).